# Latest opera won't hide the overflow while using border-radius property

Tags: overflow, opera, hidden, css

while using border-radius Opera won't actually hide the overflowing parts of elements. I already tried to apply things I managed to find in similar threads, such as defining the border style or paying attention to positioning with absolute and relative parameters. It is still not working though.

html

```
<div class="node">
    <div class="skill skill1"></div>
    <div class="skill skill2"></div>
    <div class="skill skill3"></div>
    <div class="skill skill4"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
.node {
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    opacity: 0.9;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    left: -60px;
    border: solid 1px transparent;
}

.skill {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}

.skill1 {
    background-color: #26ac79;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) skewX(45deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg) skewX(45deg);
}

.skill2 {
    background-color: #25765f;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg) skewX(45deg);
    transform: rotate(135deg) skewX(45deg);
}  

.skill3 {
    background-color: #25313f;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) skewX(45deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg) skewX(45deg);
}

.skill4 {
    background-color: #25193d;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(225deg) skewX(45deg);
    transform: rotate(225deg) skewX(45deg);
}
```

Here's the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Mu9Ar/

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the W3 specification:

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#corner-clipping

> A box's backgrounds, but not its border-image, are clipped to the
>   appropriate curve (as determined by ‘background-clip’). Other effects
>   that clip to the border or padding edge (such as ‘overflow’ other than
>   ‘visible’) also must clip to the curve. The content of replaced
>   elements is always trimmed to the content edge curve.

It appears that Firefox implemented the spec correctly by clipping the content to the edge of the curve when using `overflow: hidden`.

However, Opera is not compliant on this detail.

As an aside, if you add `border-radius` property to an `img` element, the image will be clipped correctly.

At this moment, there is no work-around that I know of unless you try HTML5 canvas.

Comment: Mhhh, guess the only solution is a bold warning 'IF YOU USE IE OR OPERA, YOU DON'T DESERVE TO VIEW THIS SITE PROPERLY' ;)

Answer (score 2):

Actually the code you provided works in latest Opera with Blink engine, so I guess you can leave your code as is. However if you need it to work in versions up to 12.16 and your page background is white, what you can do is to put .png overlay over your chart which will clip the chart, just like webdevelopers did in old days when there were no `border-radius`:)